# Loop through dict key equals to list than put in new list

Tags: python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have a rather large dictionary right now that is set up like this:

```
largedict = {'journalname':{code: 2065},'journalname1':{code: 3055}}
```

and so on and so on. And another dictionary:

```
codes = {3055: 'medicine',3786: 'sciences'}
```

And I want to loop through largedict, compare it's code value to the keys in codes. Then either add all journalname key/value pairs that match the code to a different dictionary, or delete all that don't from largedict.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dic = {journal_name : journal_body for journal_name, journal_body in largedict.items() if journal_body["code"] in codes}
```

Comment: or iteritems() in python 2.7

Comment: This throws me back: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str